# Stacking data with D3js and XML

Tags: javascript, xml, d3.js

I have an array of data in an xml document with questions and answers which looks something like this:

```
<response>
<qaData>
    <session_id>670</session_id>
    <tester_id>2273</tester_id>
    <answer_val>3</answer_val>
    <question>Do you own a GoPro?</question>
    <answer>Not yet</answer>
</qaData>
 <qaData>
    <session_id>670</session_id>
    <tester_id>2274</tester_id>
    <answer_val>2</answer_val>
    <question>Do you own a GoPro?</question>
    <answer>No</answer>
</qaData>
<qaData>
    <session_id>670</session_id>
    <tester_id>2275</tester_id>
    <answer_val>3</answer_val>
    <question>Do you own a GoPro?</question>
    <answer>Not yet</answer>
</qaData>
<qaData>
    <session_id>670</session_id>
    <tester_id>2276</tester_id>
    <answer_val>1</answer_val>
    <question>Do you own a GoPro?</question>
    <answer>Yes</answer>
</qaData>
</response>
```

What this is is a question that had the option of three different answers. Basically what Im trying to do is create a bar chart that takes the responses and displays them representing how many people selected  which answer. At the moment I can get a bar chart that simply shows each individuals answer in a separate bar

My current HTML page looks like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
  .chart div {
      font: 10px sans-serif;
      background-color: orange;
      text-align: right;
      padding: 10px;
      margin: 3px;
      color: white;
      }
</style>

</head>

<body>

   <div id="chart" class="chart">

</div>

<script>
   d3.xml("GoProTest.xml", "application/xml", function(xml) {
   d3.select("#chart")
      .selectAll("div")
      .data(xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("answer_val"))
      .enter().append("div")
      .style("width", 0)
      .style("width", function(d) { return d.textContent * 250 + "px"; })
      .data(xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("answer"))
      .text(function(d) { return d.textContent; })

});

</script>

</body>
```

Note that Im familiar with HTML and CSS but Im new to Javascript and D3js

Comment: Right now you are creating a bar chart using `div`s of different widths. I think you will have more success with D3 if you use an SVG bar chart, as [in this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304).

Comment: Also, is your question how to parse the XML data, or how to improve your bar chart code?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. What Ive got is an xml data sheet with responses to a question. 20 people gave one of three responses and Id like to display the data in a bar chart representing how many people selected each answer. At the moment my bar chart is creating an individual bar for each user.